# How to use spoilers to hide a specific word inside a sentence?

Tags: support, spoilers

How can I make a spoiler that hides only one word or sentence inside a longer text?

For example "You have been warned".

I want to hide the word "warned" with a spoiler tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spoilers hide blocks of text that are only be visible when a user moves their mouse over it. They are implemented similar 'block quotes', so they apply to paragraphs only. You cannot apply hidden text to individual words. The syntax looks like this:

>! Spoiler alert: Don't hover below, or you will be *shocked!*

> Luke,  I am your father!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You have to use a

> spoiler

for an entire line.

---

Alternatively, if the site has MathJax enabled (e.g. Puzzling), you can [color the text white](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10116):

```
You have been $\color{white}{\text{warned}}$
```

Which will look something like this on a site with Mathjax:

[image]

Comment: Note that Mathjax is enabled on very few sites and this workaround works very poorly for folks on mobile devices where highlighting blocks of text isn't quite so obvious/easy.